# Square API + iOS: OAuth not working?

Tags: ios, oauth, square, square-connect

I'm using the OAuthSwift pod to implement OAuth:

import OAuthSwift

```
class OAuthViewController: UIViewController {

  let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
    consumerKey:    "sq0idp-kXxs-e8ARPIPWeYYLTwH_w",
    consumerSecret: "sq0csp-4KnbcED665wDZ_sDYIN8E9scnYiJGqm4xxdnYtgxSKM",
    authorizeUrl:   "https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize",
    accessTokenUrl: "https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/token",
    responseType:   "code"
  )

  @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    oauthswift.authorize(
      withCallbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/edmund",
      scope: "MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ",
      state: "",
      success: { credential, response, parameters -> Void in
        print("success")
        print(credential)
      },
      failure: { error in
        print("error")
        print(error._code)
        print(error._domain)
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

My backend node / express app just redirects to open my app:

```
function edmund(req, resp) {
  console.log("resp");
  console.log(resp);
  resp.redirect(301, "indigoOMS:/");
}
```

This looks like it works:

[image]

However, it is printing the error out in my OAuth error handler:
error
-5
OAuthSwiftError
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OAuthSwiftError error -5.)

This is what gets printed out on my node log:

```
resp
ServerResponse {
  domain: null,
  _events: { finish: [Function: resOnFinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: [],
  outputEncodings: [],
  outputCallbacks: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: false,
  upgrading: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedHeader: {},
  _contentLength: null,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: false,
  _headerSent: false,
  socket:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 391,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 17,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 129529,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Object],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: [Circular] },
  connection:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 391,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 17,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 129529,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Object],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: [Circular] },
  _header: null,
  _headers: { 'x-powered-by': 'Express' },
  _headerNames: { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By' },
  _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
  req:
   IncomingMessage {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: null,
        ended: true,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: true,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 129529,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 129529,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     httpVersionMajor: 1,
     httpVersionMinor: 1,
     httpVersion: '1.1',
     complete: true,
     headers:
      { host: 'localhost:5000',
        accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-language': 'en-us',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13E233 Safari/601.1' },
     rawHeaders:
      [ 'Host',
        'localhost:5000',
        'Accept',
        'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language',
        'en-us',
        'Connection',
        'keep-alive',
        'Accept-Encoding',
        'gzip, deflate',
        'User-Agent',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13E233 Safari/601.1' ],
     trailers: {},
     rawTrailers: [],
     upgrade: false,
     url: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
     method: 'GET',
     statusCode: null,
     statusMessage: null,
     client:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 129529,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     _consuming: false,
     _dumped: false,
     next: [Function: next],
     baseUrl: '',
     originalUrl: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
     _parsedUrl:
      Url {
        protocol: null,
        slashes: null,
        auth: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        hostname: null,
        hash: null,
        search: '?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        query: 'code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        pathname: '/edmund',
        path: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        href: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        _raw: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code' },
     params: {},
     query: { code: 'sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg', response_type: 'code' },
     res: [Circular],
     body: {},
     _parsedOriginalUrl:
      Url {
        protocol: null,
        slashes: null,
        auth: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        hostname: null,
        hash: null,
        search: '?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        query: 'code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        pathname: '/edmund',
        path: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        href: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code',
        _raw: '/edmund?code=sq0cgp-eSEoyMl3mJYastHZvhucVg&response_type=code' },
     route: Route { path: '/edmund', stack: [Object], methods: [Object] } },
  locals: {} }
```

What am I missing? I feel like I'm doing everything properly.

Comment: Couple follow-up questions that might help:

1) If you log the redirect your node app is seeing, does the access token you get work?

2) Not sure how this library is designed, but do you need to specify `accessTokenUrl`? That should only be relevant for `responseType=code`.

Comment: @Troy going to update the question with the log, one sec

Comment: Another suggestion would be to try to get more stack trace out of your error (sorry, have no experience with Swift debugging, but there's got to be a way to do that).

Comment: @Troy i updated the question with my node log. Unfortunately the error object doesn't look like it has any more methods. However, I did look into the `-5` that OAuthSwiftError prints out and found this: https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/blob/9e8a62db3b8eeecacf5aaa449ef08a536f541409/Sources/OAuthSwiftError.swift#L46

Comment: oooo i printed out the description and got `serverError[No access_token, no code and no error provided by server]`... not sure how that makes any sense though...

Comment: Sorry, I realized what's up right after I posted my follow-up comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're failing to pass on any parameters to your app, because your 301 redirect is stripping them from the URI. Maybe something like this?

```
var URL = require('url');
...

function edmund(req, resp) {
  console.log("resp");
  console.log(resp);
  var queryString = URL.parse(req.url).query;
  resp.redirect(301, "indigoOMS:/?" + queryString);
}
```

Comment: i'll try it out now, one sec!

Comment: is uri an npm package?

Comment: Yes, i think it should be built in. You can also just split the request URL on a '?', but that feels less safe.

EDIT: Oops I'm a dummy, it's URL. Haven't written node in a while.

Comment: ok i have to go but i will work on this tomorrow, will definitely keep you updated. thanks for your help Troy! this looks promising!!

Comment: it works! i used: `let url_parts = URL.parse(req.url, true);` and `url_parts.query`

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URL needs to be a webpage hosted with on a server, you aren't going to have luck trying to redirect to a mobile app. If you are building an application for personal use, you could use your personal access token instead. What kind of app are you building?

Comment: Theoretically this should be workable, since OP has set up a little server on localhost to receive the request (note that localhost is an explicitly allowed exception to the "https only" rule).

Comment: yeh as @Troy mentioned it does work since i set up localhost. the server does get a request from Square and my app does end up opening, but OAuthSwift is still printing `error`

Comment: Yeah, but if you are just going to be using the API on localhost machines, it is much easier to use your personal access token instead of doing OAuth. And if you plan on using the API on machines other than your own, then the localhost server approach won't work.